# Как достать значение стиля из style при помощи xpath PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Есть блок:

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url(/image.jpg)">                                            
 ....
</div>
```

Как составить выражение xpath чтобы достать **/image.jpg**?

Answer (score 0):

Может вам подойдет вот такое решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409244/creating-preg-match-using-xpath-in-php  ? Это если я вас правильно понял и вам нужен поиск в тексте атрибута по регулярному выражению. Ведь если найти нужные узлы, то из них вытащить любой атрибут и обработать его значение средствами PHP не представляет труда.